# Regex: Negative lookahead with capturing group not from beginning

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have achieved a regular expression in Javascript which can match a navigator.userAgent string from Safari and not from iPad:

```
/^(?!.*Mobile).*Safari/i
```

My problem is that when doing the match this returns the whole string:

```
var pattern = /^(?!.*Mobile).*Safari/i;

var pc = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2";

var ipad = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B146 Safari/8536.25";

ipad.match(pattern); // Returns null
pc.match(pattern);   // Returns ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari"]
```

What I want in the last line is to return only:

```
["Safari"]
```

I've made some research and I know you can remove the capturing group nature from a regex by doing (?:term) or (?is:term), but it doesn't even compile with negative lookahead (at least in Safari). I tried also capturing with brackets the "Safari" at the end of the match, but it returns a second element inside the array.

Does anyone know how can I accomplish this within an only regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain this `expression in Javascript which can match a navigator.userAgent string from Safari and not from iPad:` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Safari has navigator.userAgent containing "Safari" for both the PC version and iPad version, but only the iPad version has the "Mobile" or also the "iPad" substrings. So I think the easiest way of differencing them is when defining the Safari for PC pattern, removing all results with Mobile or iPad (I could as well have written     /^(?!.*Mobile).*Safari/i       )

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That doesn't work, at least in Safari for PC. I've just tested it in the console.

Comment: Then you have a serious bug in your regex. Use `/(?:Mobile)?\s+(Safari)/i`.

Comment: Both returning [" Safari", "Safari"]

Comment: I've edited the main post and made some JS code for clearing things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a way for returning only ["Safari"] but I found that for recognizing browsers, which was my goal, is much better using the test() method in the pattern object.

Some examples:

```
/^(?!.*(ipad|chrome)).*safari.*$/i.test(navigator.userAgent); // true for Safari
/^(?!.*(ipad|chrome)).*windows.*safari.*$/i.test(navigator.userAgent); // true only for Safari in Windows
/iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent); // true only for iPad
```